# I want to add Tabs like android in my swift Ios application

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

How can I add android like tabs in my app, like these in image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this link and learn how to add them

[Material Tabs iOS](https://material.io/components/tabs/ios#using-tabs)

Installing

In order to use MDCTabBarView, first, add the component to your Podfile:

`pod MaterialComponents/Tabs+TabBarView`

Then, run pod install:
`pod install`

After that, import the relevant target or file.

SWIFT

> import MaterialComponents.MaterialTabs_TabBarView

OBJECTIVE-C

> #import <MaterialComponents/MaterialTabs+TabBarView.h>

From there, initialize an **MDCTabBarView** and add it to your view controller's view.

Comment: Do not post link only answers, links can disappear or be changed. Add a brief explanation of the content of the linked page and describe how it answers the question.

Comment: I am not able to pod install MaterialComponents

Comment: @MohmedAnisAgwan I have added instructions on how to use material tabs, please check.